# How I can check if a string is defined or not?

Tags: c, string

I have codes as below.
I wanna check if a string is defined or not using **`isdefined`** function. 
How I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define string char*

bool isdefined(string str){
     /*do something*/
}

int main(){
    string hw;                 //print NO if I write this line
    string hw = "Hello World"; //print YES if I write this line
    if(isdefined(hw))
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By "defined" you mean "initilized"? No way you can do this. Since you are the one writing the code, you always know it anyway.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible.

All you can do is check for it not being `NULL`, but an un-initialized automatic variable is *not* guaranteed to be set to any particular value so it won't work for the code you've shown.

Also "defined" is not the proper term here, it means something else in C.